# How do I update Subscriber attributes with Java SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

I am using com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETSubscriberService to update subscriber information.  The other SDKs have examples like:
subscriber.props['Attributes'] = [{'Name' => 'First Name', 'Value' => 'ExactTarget Example'}]
I was expecting to add attributes/data to com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.model.ETSubscriber and post it.
Is this the wrong approach with the Java SDK?

Thanks for you help,
Kevin

Comment: It does look like the ETSubscriber object doesn't have a property for Attributes so it would need to be added in order to support profile attributes.  If you make that change, create a pull request back into the GitHub repo so it can be evaluated and integrated in.

Comment: Mac - isn't that the answer? Make it so!

Answer (score 1):

It does look like the ETSubscriber object doesn't have a property for Attributes so it would need to be added in order to support profile attributes. If you make that change, create a pull request back into the GitHub repo so it can be evaluated and integrated in